# How do I configure vSwitch with OpenStack

Tags: networking, configuration, openstack

I am setting up an openstack installation on a single node, but configure it so I can add more nodes later for various services (nova, swift mainly). To do this I use the 2 ethernet connections: `eth0` for communicating with the internet and `eth1` for internal communication (not currently used since single node installation) (following [this guide](https://github.com/mseknibilel/OpenStack-Grizzly-Install-Guide/blob/OVS_SingleNode/OpenStack_Grizzly_Install_Guide.rst)).

To bridge from my router into the openstack virtual network, I am using openVSwitch, and have configured 2 bridges as follows

```
#br-int will be used for VM integration
ovs-vsctl add-br br-int

#br-ex is used to make to access the internet
ovs-vsctl add-br br-ex
```

I then configure my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# VM internet Access
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
up ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
up ip link set eth0 promisc on
down ip link set eth0 promisc off
down ifconfig eth0 down

# add a static ip to the host machine to facilitate interet access
auto br-ex
iface br-ex inet static
address 192.168.100.51
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.100.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

I reboot my machine and run

```
ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex eth0
```

To connect the bridge to eth0.

Now, I can communicate with computers on my local subnet, but I cannot communicate through my router. I assume this is a router issue, but I am not sure. Also, if it is a router problem, what will the settings to allow this setup to work be called?

EDIT:
I found a guide [here](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~rlug/help/net-debug.html) which says problems getting past the router can be due to routing - here is my routing table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.200   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br-ex
10.10.100.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-ex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was indeed solved by altering the routing tables. The problem was that my gateway was actually on `192.168.1.1`. I fixed the problem by removing the default record with `ip route del default`, and adding in a default route for my gateway with `ip route add default 192.168.1.1 dev br-ex`